# Two equal strings return false when compared with .equals()

Tags: java, string

"Given two strings, return true if either of the strings appears at the very end of the other string, ignoring upper/lower case differences (in other words, the computation should not be "case sensitive")."

When I put the two variables through testing, the substring is equal to the shorter of the two strings, but it still returns false in my if statement.

This is my attempt at the solution on coding bat regarding strings. I've stored the strings as new strings to eliminate case sensitivity. The link can be found [here](http://codingbat.com/prob/p126880) for reference.[1](http://codingbat.com/prob/p126880)

```
public boolean endOther(String a, String b) {

  String x = a.toLowerCase();
  String y = b.toLowerCase();
  int xl = a.length();
  int yl = b.length();

  if(xl > yl && x.substring(yl, xl).equals(y)) return true;
  if(xl < yl && y.substring(xl, yl).equals(x)) return true;
  if(xl == yl && x.equals(y)) return true;
  else return false;
}
```

Comment: what is you input?

Comment: after reading the task at hand within the provided link, I would simply use [String#endsWith](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)).

Comment: The program is testing for any instance of string a and b. I've attached the link to the problem on coding bat for reference.

Comment: suppose your question is bit unclear. But from the link you provided you can find a solution with String class mehtod `endsWith()` use `{ }` in the if clauses for clear coe.

Comment: `return x.endsWith(y) || y.endsWith(x);` and be done with it.

Comment: Your substring indexes are not correct. You want to compare, for example, string `y` with the *last* `y.length()` characters of `x`, not the characters from `y.length()` to the end of `x`. For example, what if `x.length() == 10` and `y.length() == 9`? Then you'd compare the last one-character-long substring of `x` (from index `9` to the end) to all of `y`. Clearly a string of length `1` cannot equal a string of length `9`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the overloaded version of the substring you're using is unnecessary considering all you have to do is check if one of the strings ends with the other.

- if `xl` is greater than `yl`, all you have to do is
  `x.substring(xl-yl).equals(y)`, meaning your substring should start at `xl-yl` until the end of the `String`.
- if `xl` is less than `yl`, all you have to do is `y.substring(yl-xl).equals(x)`, meaning your substring should start at `yl-xl` until the end of the `String`.

full solution:

```
public boolean endOther(String a, String b) {
        String x = a.toLowerCase();
        String y = b.toLowerCase();
        int xl = a.length();
        int yl = b.length();

        if(xl > yl && x.substring(xl-yl).equals(y)) return true;
        if(xl < yl && y.substring(yl-xl).equals(x)) return true;
        if(xl == yl && x.equals(y)) return true;
        else return false;
}
```

However, as mentioned within the comments you're better off using [String#endsWith](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith(java.lang.String)).